# Exclude array type field from selection in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm working with Google Analytics raw data in BigQuery. I'm trying to do a simple query: select all fields except one that is a RECORD type. I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * Except(hits.sourcePropertyInfo.*)  FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_20191125`
```

but I get an error like this

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [1:21]
```

These are the fields that I want to exclude

```
field                                               | type
-----------------------------------------------------------
hits.sourcePropertyInfo                             | RECORD
hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName   | STRING
hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId    | STRING
```

What is the proper way to do this type of exclusion?

Comment: I tried different versions, without * etc and I'm getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to re-build the contents of the array `hits` using a subquery and feed its outputs back into an array:

```sql
SELECT 
  * replace( 
      array(select as struct * except(sourcePropertyInfo) from unnest(hits))  
      AS hits 
    )
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20190101` 
LIMIT 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove subfields of a nested struct.  You can do this in multiple steps, though:

```
SELECT ga.* EXCEPT (hits),
       hits.* EXCEPT (hits.sourcePropertyInfo)
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions_20191125` ga
```

Comment: This one raises an error:

Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [2:27]